# Email can't be send with cronjob "Recipient names must be specified"

Tags: php, linux, email, web

I'm programming a php script who's checking every minute some things. If the status of the things aren't good it will send mails to some persons.
I've got apache2 on my linux server. When I open the php script, it works wonderfully. But when my Crontab opens it, it gives me that little error here:

```
Recipient names must be specified
```

I created a file whos just sending a mail to myself.

```
<?php
$to = " Surename Familyname <blablabla@gugus.com>";
$subject = "Testian";
$message = "Was geht ab?";
$header = "From: testian@abacus.ch\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: Recipient Name <testian@test.com>\r\n";

if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $header)){
    echo "Error -> ".error_get_last();
}else{
    echo "sent";
}?>
```

So when I open the file by myself in my browser, it works fine! I get the email and everything is good.
But when the crontab runs it, I always get this error.

Everything works but just the mail won't be sent...

Comment: Ever fiugure this out?